# My Login PHP script is malfunctioning

Tags: php, mysql, post

So I am having problems with my login script. I have a salted MD5 hash stored in my database, and well... When I use this statement followed by this code, it logs in whatever the password is.

I'm not sure if it's the syntax, or it's just the way I use it, but it logs in if the user exists even if the password is 'lalala' and the person types in 'chicken'.

```
$sql = ("select * from website where `Email`='$user' and `Password`='$pass'");
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if ($query) {
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    if (sizeof($data) > 0) {
        $_SESSION['vuser'] = $_POST['vuser'];
        header('Location: /');
        die;
    }
}
```

This is how it is run:

index.php --> Presses login (Sends POST data) --> login.php (This script) --> (If it logs in, it returns to /index.php, but if not, it will go to /login.php.

I have a test account on there called 'blah' with the salted MD5 hashed as 'lolcatz'. If I were to type in 'blah' in the username part, with the password as 'stackoverflow', it will go to 'index.php'
Any ideas?

Comment: mysql_* statements are deprecated, you should be using PDO. Also, rather than basing the login off the num of rows returned, why not use `password_verify()` since I assume you are already using `password_hash()` or something of the like...

Comment: I don't see any salt or md5 in your code. Anyway: did you try to `print_r( $data )` ?

Comment: Scheintod, I Salt and MD5 hash it. That code is just a snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect. `mysql_fetch_array()` will return an array representing one SINGLE row of data from the query results, or a boolean FALSE in case of failure (query has no rows, or you're fetching from something OTHER than a query result).

You should be doing:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    ... user exists ...
} else {
    ... user does not exist ...
}
```

Comment: @KeirDavis if you ever plan to upgrade your PHP you should really get used to using PDO sooner than later....

Comment: Thanks A.O. I will do :) This is just for a small server at home, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

try to `print_r($data)` to see what the `mysql_fetch_array` function returns. It could be that it returns FALSE, which will overpass your condition `if (sizeof($data) > 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use this:

```
if ($query) {
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    if (sizeof($data) > 0) {
        $_SESSION['vuser'] = $_POST['vuser'];
        header('Location: /');
        die;
    }
}
```

What is the reason behind measuring the size of data? That is a poor way to validate.

Do this instead :

```
if ($query) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
        // In the above line, we check a user with that username and password exists
        $_SESSION['vuser'] == $_POST['vuser'];
        header('Location: /');
     } else echo "Bad password";
} else echo "Connection error";
```

As a side note, please stop using mysql_* functions now or real soon. They are going to be removed in the next version of PHP, and are less secure. You can use the PHP PDO Class.

I am also assuming you are not storing the $username and $pass directly in the database. If you are, stop it now, and use hash functions to store the password. You can use md5 and/or sha1 hash methods.

Comment: I agree that passwords should not be stored in plaintext, but be aware that MD5 and SHA1 are both considered too weak these days for the purpose of password hashing.

Comment: Agreed. It's always better to mix up multiple salts and use multiple rounds of hashing to store passwords. I myself would recommend a good hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

As it is said, you can also use mysqli similar down below

```
$dbq=("SELECT * FROM users where username='$uname'");
$dbresult=mysqli_query($con,$dbq);
```

where $con is the connection query which you've to write in mysqli.

Now you can fetch the data similar down below.

```
$obj=$dbresult->fetch_object();
$dbmail=$obj->Email;
$dbuname=$obj->Password;
```

Comment: @halfer Sorry about that. All I tried is explain why the answer is wrong. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Sasanka, okay thanks. I'm voting this one up, as the mysql library is deprecated, as you correctly pointed out in your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $sql = ("select * from website where `Email`='$user' and `Password`='$pass'");
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    if ($row) {

            $_SESSION['vuser'] = $_POST['vuser'];
            header('Location:"go where ever you want to i dont care"');

        }
   else{ //some error message}
```

Comment: You did the same thing as the OP

Comment: If your answer is right it wouldn't have received any downvotes. I don't think I need to follow what you say.

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri: why to go with downvotes? when all you need to do is, just run that query on your end. BTW i can downvote yours too before even lookin at what you have written does that make your code invalid?

Comment: I do not downvote without looking at the code. Okay, let me explain the mistakes:
1. Not specifying where the OP went wrong.
2. Using mysql_fetch_array to validate is bad.
3. Why are you including "die" in your code? It will terminate the execution.
4. No explanation of how the code you posted works.

Please try to help the OP, the code alone doesn't speak

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri: the code i written was no rocket science, as you youself said i did the same what OP did,although it wasn't. so i dont think explanation was necessary. the die thing is a genuine mistake. i am gonna change that. Can you tell me why using fetch array to validate is a bad idea?

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri: about looking the code,i can guess what you saw by your first comment.

Comment: When mysql_query returns true/false, mysql_fetch_array would not be processed. That means $row holds something other than true, or stay undefined. The "IF($row)" doesn't need to evaluate to false in this case, which would actually log the user in and grant him a session parameter.

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri: FYI-> 1) "The mysql_fetch_array() function returns a row from a recordset as an associative array and/or a numeric array.

This function gets a row from the mysql_query() function and returns an array on success, or FALSE on failure or when there are no more rows."
2) mysql_query()..This function returns the query handle for SELECT queries, TRUE/FALSE for other queries, or FALSE on failure.

Now i beleive i should downvote you too :)

Comment: When mysql_query returns True/false, how would you exactly preform fetch_array? Do you think it would get through? In that case what would $row hold?

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri: The query in context is a select query, so it would return a handle for it or false in case of failures. so mysql_fetch_array would return an array or false. In any case the if or else statement would get executed. So what exactly would stop to get through?